# Github pages vite JS build not showing the images

Tags: backend, vite

I'm trying to make simple portfolio using Github pages but something is wrong with the images. I can't load them. Can you help me how to fix that?

[image]

https://xakepa.github.io/Portfolio/

Here is my build folder. I used Vite and Three libraries
https://github.com/xakepa/Portfolio/tree/main/dist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem. It was in the loading. For example

```
const spaceTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("./images/space.jpg");
```

The problem was in the patch I tried ("./images/space.jpg"); or ("/images/space.jpg"); but these working only local, doesn't work in github pages.

The correct way is without any dash or dot and

```
("images/space.jpg");
```

Comment: Correct and it's worth linking the documentation of Vite about that - You can find more information on "How to handle static asset" in Vite here: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, I solved it by adding the images in the `public folder` inside the `root` instead of the `src folder`, like this `public/assets/img`

and the img src will be like this
`<img src="/assets/img/downlaod.png" />`

```
 ─┬root
  |
  ├─public/assets/img
  ├─src
  ├─.gitignore
  ├─vite.config.js
  ├─README.md
  ├─dist
  ├─.yarn
```

Comment: This _sort of_ worked, but I had warnings from the build `new URL('./assets/images/noentry.jpg', import.meta.url) doesn't exist at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime` and the images were placed in a  subfolder of `dist\assets`

Answer (score 3):

it is quite simple, if you don't want to read the Vite documentation  here https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory
I can save you time)))

Just create a public directory, build your project and you will see all your images in the "dist" directory by the same path but without the "public" prefix

here is a code example of how to render images, but note that you wouldn't see it in the developer environment (it is normal according to Vite documentation)

```
<img
    loading="lazy" <--- not necessary 
    src={`/icons/flags/${dynamicImageName}.png`} <--- here 
/>
```

[image: folders on you project]