# Blank page when deploying a react app to github pages and vite

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, github-pages, vite

When i try to deploy my react app to github pages with the package gh-pages, the result page is blank.[result page](https://elvas.me/react-testing/)

The page I am trying to deploy is here: [LINK](https://github.com/sdrrv/react-testing)
I don't know if it matters but I am currently using the free domain given to me by GitHub: [www.elvas.me](http://www.elvas.me)

I tried following the react official docs: [Link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages), but it didn't work for me... Perhaps it's because I am using vite and not create-react-app?

***Edit***

Found out that the site is trying to get the .js and the .css from the wrong place.
[image]

I just don't know what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Have you set the "/" route ?

Comment: How do I do that? In the index.html?

Comment: I mean in the app.js, where you define your routes, is the "/" (the home route) defined ?

Comment: I don't think it is... But I am not using react-router, do I need it?

Comment: If you only have one route, no. But if you want to develop many routes in the future, I recommend you to use react-router.

Comment: For this specific project, i do not need more than one route :)

Comment: Did you do `npm run build`? It looks like your files aren't the build files in the github repo

Comment: I did! I am using yarn, so `yarn run build`. The files don't look the same because I was testing stuff, but now it's all updated. Still not working tho.

Comment: when i do `yarn deploy`, it will automatically do the `yarn run build` right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so to solve this the only thing that I had to do was to add `base:"{repName}"` to the **vite.config.ts** file.

Source: https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html

The images were not loading, I used this to fix them:
[Github pages vite JS build not showing the images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68758939/github-pages-vite-js-build-not-showing-the-images)

Answer (score 8):

I see that you have managed to deploy your React project to Github pages successfully, but here is how I did it in case anyone needs help:

- First things first, make sure that your ".git" folder and your project are in the same folder.

[image]

1. Run `npm run build`. You should have a `dist` folder now.
2. Open the file `vite.config.js` (or `.ts`).
3. Add the `base` file with your repository name. Include the two `/`.

Example: let's say your github project's URL is `https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd`.

```
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/react-beautiful-dnd/",
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

3. Open your `.gitignore` file and **delete** the `dist` line from it. You want to make sure that the `dist` folder is pushed to github.
4. `git add .`
5. `git commit -m "deploy"`
6. `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`
7. Wait for a couple minutes (in my case it took 4 minutes) and open the page. In the example above, the URL would look like this: **https://atlassian.github.io/react-beautiful-dnd**

In case it's still showing a blank page, it's very likely to do with the step number 3. Ensure you added the correct repository URL and that it begins and ends with the `/` sign.

That is about it, I hope it helps. [I used this blog post for guidance](https://towardsdev.com/deploying-react-application-to-github-pages-with-vite-2d3e32ae97e7), it is a more detailed explanation of the above.

Answer (score 3):

### Make sure that

1. `vite.config.js` contains `base` set to your repository name.
   For `https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO>`  your `vite.config.js` file should be something like this.

```
/*
...
*/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    base: "/<REPO>/",
});
```

2. If you are using **react route** then set  `basename`  as your `<REPO>` name for `<BrowserRoute>` component.
   Your `main.jsx` file should be something like this.

```
/*
...
*/

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter basename={"/<REPO>/"}>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I had issue deploying on github pages  as I didn't set the `basename` property.

**For more details check [here](https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-deploy-your-vite-react-app-to-github-pages-with-and-without-react-router-b060d912b10e)**

*Hope this will find helpful to someone.*

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else encountering this problem in the future and finding this thread: Check your file names very carefully for your `vite.config.ts` and such. I'd accidentally misnamed `vite.config.ts` as `vite.config.js` (which one you use MUST match `tsconfig.node.json`). Everything worked just fine in preview until I tried to deploy, and suddenly, white screen. Took me a couple hours to figure out what was going wrong.

Also, if you're using a custom domain, the proper base is `"/"` which is also the default (nothing).

And finally, there's a lot of blog posts giving you suggestions about what github action to use. When the one from the docs didn't work, I tried using others that were recommended in such guides. But when I fixed the underlying problem, my deploy still didn't work; it was only when returning to the [suggested config from the actual documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages) that my deploy was successful.

There's a lot to mess up on, hopefully as vite matures, there are more correct answers and (relatively) fewer wrong ones, and I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I beat my head against a wall with this issue for many hours.

I had correctly set the base in my config file, but it wasn't being prepended to the 'assets' folder path during the `vite build` of `dist/index.html`. Check your `dist/index.html` after build to make sure base is being prepended correctly.

It took me a long time to figure out why the prepend didn't work. It turned out to be because the vanilla Vite React template I used to initialize the project had placed my `vite.config.js` file in the `src` subdirectory, whereas it should have been in the root directory. After moving it to the root, `vite build` worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure those things

1. the dist folder is not in the .`gitignore` file
2. in the `vite.config.js` file the base name should be repository name
3. all route bases should be start with the repository name

Comment: I think is a good practice to put dist in gitignore, because besides being necessary data in the repository, it can create conflicts when you are working with a team.

Answer (score 0):

On the top of everything that has been pointed out, another possible error (which I did):

When configuring Github Actions on the repository, the default content shown in the workflow static.yml looked awfully similar to that suggested in the vite documentation page. So I did not bother to change the default suggestion and committed it.

The culprit in the default suggestion was :

```
with:
          # Upload entire folder
          path: '.'
```

Vite documentation rightfully pointed out which I ignored:

```
with:
          # Upload dist folder
          path: './dist'
```

This final change had my project working!